# why 0xfffffffc is an invalid address to access?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, y86

Hi I was reading an textbook,it says that programs are not allowed to access addresses greater
than `0xc0000000` (as is the case for 32-bit versions of Linux), so below assembly code is invalid:

```
1. irmovl $1,%eax
2. xorl %esp,%esp // Set stack pointer to 0 and CC to 100
3. pushl %eax    // Attempt to write to 0xfffffffc, will fail
```

I'm confused. and I have two questions:

1. why programs are not allowed to access addresses greater than `0xc0000000`, isn't that address like `0xc0000008` a valid address?
2. if programs are really not allowed to access addresses greater than `0xc0000000`, `0xfffffffc` is lower(less) than `0xc0000000`, so why it will fail?

Comment: There's nothing about the CPU that makes addresses greater than 0xc0000000 invalid. That is an operating system decision.

Comment: The default configuration for Linux is to put the kernel in the upper 1gb (>= 0xC0000000) of memory. This 1gb of krnel memory is mapped into the address space of all user mode programs so is by default off limits to user mode code.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFC is greater than 0xC0000000.

Comment: Linux doesn't run on y86, AFAIK.  Are you really asking about x86 Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. why programs are not allowed to access addresses greater than 0xc0000000, isn't that address like 0xc0000008 a valid address?

Modern operating systems leverage features of the hardware to prevent running applications from interfering with each other. The primary components of this isolation are *privilege separation* and *virtual memory*.

Virtual memory (as opposed to *physical memory*) means that the addresses accessed by code (e.g. a `mov` instruction) aren't actual addresses of RAM. Instead, the *memory management unit* (MMU) leverages the *page tables* to *translate* virtual addresses (VA) to physical addresses (PA) before sending them out to RAM.

Privilege separation is enforced by the CPU (and MMU), and is what allows for a single operating system *kernel* to have total control of the hardware, while safely running multiple *user* applications.

Putting these two concepts together, typically the kernel runs in one region of virtual memory (inaccessible to userspace), and userspace processes run in another part.

In the x86 32-bit arch port of the Linux kernel, a 1-3 split is often used, to provide 1 GB of VA space to the kernel, leaving 3 GB of VA space for each user application. Thus:

- 0x00000000 - 0xBFFFFFFF : Userspace
- 0xC0000000 - 0xFFFFFFFF : Kernel

> 2. if programs are really not allowed to access addresses greater than 0xc0000000, 0xfffffffc is lower(less) than 0xc0000000, so why it will fail?

There's a big difference between how data is *represented* (e.g. in a hardware register or in memory) and how it is *interpreted* (e.g. signed/unsigned integer, floating point number, text string, image, etc.)

Note that if you *interpret* 0xFFFFFFFF as a 32-bit two's-compliment (signed) integer, you get -1. If you interpret it as an unsigned integer, you get (2^32 - 1) = 4294967295.

Addresses are always unsigned; very generally speaking, there are no negative numbers when it gets down to the hardware.

0xFFFFFFFC is greater than 0xC0000000. Thus, here it is a kernel address, and any userspace application that tries to access it will fault and be delivered a SIGSEGV signal.

Comment: Note for anyone experimenting with this on a real modern x86 Linux system: a 32-bit process under a 64-bit kernel can use all 4 GiB of virtual address space, except for the low 64k (reserved by default so NULL pointer deref faults instead of silently succeeding: https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr), and the high 2 pages.  [Why can't I mmap(MAP\_FIXED) the highest virtual page in a 32-bit Linux process on a 64-bit kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47712502).)  The 1:3 or 2:2 split is only when you're running a 32-bit kernel as well as 32-bit userspace, or 64-bit process + kernel.