# The function of "main" address remains unchanged. Why does local variable address change every run?

Tags: c, linux

Please refer to the below program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int a, b;
        printf("address of main =%p\n", main);
        a=3;
        printf("Address of 'a' =%p\n", &a);
        return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above program using `gcc` and then ran the binary. I am getting the below output:

```
[root@localhost gdb]# ./a.out
address of main =0x400536
Address of 'a' =0x7ffc4802cbdc
[root@localhost gdb]# ./a.out
address of main =0x400536
Address of 'a' =0x7ffe2bdcd66c
[root@localhost gdb]#
```

Same source code compiled with `–m32`, now I'm getting the output:

```
[root@localhost gdb]# ./a.out
address of main =0x804841b
Address of 'a' =0xffa6b29c
[root@localhost gdb]# ./a.out
address of main =0x804841b
Address of 'a' =0xff9b808c
```

Here is my question: why the address of `a` variable range has changed while running 64 and 32 bits application in 64 bit kernel?. The `main` function address remains unchanged, Why does `a` variable addresses change every run? And where is the address of `a` variable stored?

Comment: How would a 32-bit program be able to use a 64-bit address space? It doesn't, 32 bits means 32 bits.

Comment: Also please read about [ASLR (Address Space Layout Radnomization)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: Lastly please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please, one question per question.

Comment: You have a position-dependent executable, so you don't have code ASLR, only stack ASLR.  If you built a PIE, you'd get a varying address for `main`, too.  (But 32-bit PIE is slow, don't actually use it.)  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more about PIE vs. non-PIE.

Comment: This had nothing to do with embedded systems or assembly, please don't abuse tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software that loads programs intentionally varies the location of the stack in each execution to make it harder for attackers to exploit bugs.

The program knows where `a` is because its offset within the stack frame of `main` is built into it by the compiler, and the address of the stack frame for `main` comes from the stack pointer passed to `main` by the software that loads the program and starts `main`.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Another doubt is that the 3: 1 memory splits are not applicable to 32-bit applications on 64-bit kernels. That's what address of "a" variable is stored in outside of 3GB of address space. is it right here?

Comment: @user3172612: yes, Linux always puts the user-space stack at a virtual address near the top of the user-space range.  For 32-bit user-space under a 64-bit kernel, that's near the highest possible address.  (But not quite, because the VDSO claims the top two usable pages, and the highest page is reserved for pointer-values that mean "error" inside the kernel.  See [Why can't I mmap(MAP\_FIXED) the highest virtual page in a 32-bit Linux process on a 64-bit kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47712502).