# Setting heap size in Java

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-size

I am trying to run a Java tool in Linux Ubuntu system and I keep getting the following error after the program imports 12% of the data:

```
Fata Error:
Exception in thread 'Thread-l" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java heap space
```

I tried to set the heap size using

```
java -Xms8G -Xmx16G -jar Haploview.jar
```

but the error appears again exactly at same point after just using less than 500M Of the allocated Ram. 
Using the command 'free -m' I can see that there are lots of free RAM memory left but I don't know why Java do not use it

Comment: An `OutOfMemoryError` might appear when when your physical system is low on memory. You allow the JVM to take up to 16Gib, but does your physical machine actually have that much memory _available_?

Comment: Yes, it is a local server with 64G of RAM.

Comment: But what else is running?  If you `cat /proc/meminfo`, you have enough `MemAvailable`?

Comment: You can use something like `jconsole` to track what's happening with the heap.  Out of curiosity what is your code doing when the exception occurs?  Do you have a stack?  Jconsole docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/management/using-jconsole.htm#JSMGM-GUID-258E47A7-78AC-4B73-B4E1-E06E4DD4FDDC

Comment: MemTotal:       131947892 kB _
MemFree:        81041836 kB_
MemAvailable:   109647548 kB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- According to the specification Haploview allocates 512 MB of memory by default. You can increase the memory up to 2000 MB via java -jar Haploview.jar -memory 2000.
  For details see https://www.broadinstitute.org/haploview/frequent-questions
- But a memory larger than 2 GB is most likely not possible because Haploview seems to be a 32-bit application which is limited to a memory
  of 2 GB independent of the underlying OS (32 Bit or 64 Bit).
  See https://haploview.software.informer.com/download/
  and [Memory limit to a 32-bit process running on a 64-bit Linux OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079519/memory-limit-to-a-32-bit-process-running-on-a-64-bit-linux-os)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that you have to set memory size once for the java and once for the program independently.I can see that haploview is using more than 9Gb of memory more than what you expected. But it seems to be working completely fine now.